# Office 2010 : Custom ribbon

Tags: excel, ms-office

What is the best way to have a bookmark of commands for MS office application (mainly excel, project). For example, I need to group some of the most used reports in MS project or buttons to invoke a macro. Something like custom ribbon (with a tab and action buttons) would do, but the problem is it affect all the files. I want to do per file basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ribbon customization in Excel can be done on a per file basis in 2007 and 2010.  The excel file container is a .zip file that contains an XML file that details any ribbon customization.

You can get the basics from this msdn article:

[Display and Hide Tabs, Groups, and Controls on the Microsoft Office Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee390805%28office.11%29.aspx)

It's written by Ron de Bruin, his website is http://www.rondebruin.nl/tips.htm which has some additional resources for ribbon customization.

For re purposing existing excel commands the structure is fairly simple and should be readily achievable for your purpose.

Comment: Ron's page is filled with awesome sauce! So many great tips and tricks.